# sql get couple of elements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, math

I have the following sql table:

```
| ID | numbers                     |
|----|-----------------------------|
|  1 | 1,3,19,23,28,32,39,42,60,80 |
|  2 | 1,3,18,24,29,33,40,43,61,80 |
|  3 | 1,2,3,25,30,34,41,44,62,78  |
```

In Numbers I have a string with 10 numbers.

I want to get all couple of two elements (and if it is possible for three, four etc) in SQL Server or MySQL.

For example for two elements:

- 1,3 appers in all rows (3 times)
- 1, 80 appears in the first and second row (2 times)

etc

I tried to split numbers from every row and insert into a temporary table and after generate combinations of 10 choose k (where k is numbers of elements in a couple) but something doesn't work. I don't know if it's the best idea.

My code in this moment: http://pastebin.com/qRjPdfay

Thanks

Comment: 1. Please post all of relevant your code ***in the question***, not in external files.  (And please post it after trimming it down to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.)

Comment: 2. On stackoverflow.com, "something doesn't work" will not work as a description of a problem.  Please describe *precisely* what you expected to happen, and *precisely* what happened instead.

Comment: You should use a [second normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) which would make solving your problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, splitting your numbers coulmns to rows would make things easier. If you are using MySQL you could use a query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2 AS
SELECT
  ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers, ',', n),',',-1) AS number
FROM
  mytable CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS n
                      UNION ALL SELECT 10 AS n) d;
```

(this will work if all numbers contains exactly 10 numbers an no less, if there are less this query needs some improvements). Then you can count the time each number appears:

```
SELECT number, COUNT(*) as appears
FROM mytable2
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY appears DESC
```

and you can group number by the number of times they appear:

```
SELECT
  appears, GROUP_CONCAT(number) AS numbers
FROM (
    SELECT number, COUNT(*) as appears
    FROM mytable2
    GROUP BY number
    ORDER BY appears DESC
  ) g
GROUP BY
  appears
ORDER BY
  appears DESC
```

(MySQL only) and the result will be like this:

```
| appears | numbers       |
|---------|---------------|
|       3 | 3,1           |
|       2 | 80            |
|       1 | 43,23,40..... |
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a73d3/5).